# iron:router - how to override what value is used for _id with {{pathFor}}

Tags: meteor

I will try explain this the best way I can.

In the application I am building, there are three main views:

- A list of competitions
- A view dedicated to each competition (listing games and links to games)
- A view dedicated to each game

I have two collections:

- Competitions
- Games

**My question**: On the third view (game view), I want to have a link which will go back to the competition view. I know that I could just use the back/history to load the URL. After trying to do it and failing a couple times, I want to work out how to do this.

I have this code:

```
<a href="{{pathFor 'competition'}}">&larr; Back</a>
```

However it feeds the `_id` from the Game collection, rather than the Competition collection... not sure how I would even override that. I need it to use `Games.competition` rather than `Games._id`

---

As per Mário's answer, I was able to use a helper like so:

```
<a href="{{pathFor 'competition' _id=competition}}">&larr;</a>
```

This works exactly as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simple, iron:router provides: `{{pathFor 'competition' _id=someHelperValue}}`